# Dynamic Custom Code Escaping in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have the following two snippets of code that render the custom code in the `header.php` and `footer.php`:

```
<!-- code before closing head tag -->
<?php echo $x_redux_option['x_code_before_head']; ?>
<!-- code before closing body tag -->
<?php echo $x_code_before_body; ?>
```

The data is coming from the `redux framework` dynamically.
And the options only accept code wrapped with `script tags` and `HTML markup` that is valid inside the `<head> tag for header` and `valid HTML markup for footer`.

The fact is that the `Mentor Themeforest` shows the following errors:

1. All dynamic data must be correctly escaped for the context where it is rendered. at file `header.php`, line 39:
2. All dynamic data must be correctly escaped for the context where it is rendered. at file `footer.php`, line 44:

---

How can I escape this data?
Will I use the `wp_kses()` function? 
But which `HTML tags` should I allow? 
How can I know which tags should be allowed?

Please, extend your helping hand as before. :)
Thank you so much for taking the trouble to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with `esc_html`. Since you are going to echo HTML and scripts, `wp_kses` would need to allow pretty much all the tags. Your code is gonna look like this:

```
<!-- code before closing head tag -->
<?php echo esc_html( $x_redux_option['x_code_before_head'] ); ?>
<!-- code before closing body tag -->
<?php echo esc_html( $x_code_before_body ); ?>
```

I suppose you're familiar with data escaping, however I'll leave a link to official WordPress docs anyway:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Thank you so much, Luca :) . Yes, I am familiar with data escaping. My concern is that if esc_html() is the best practice for this purpose. Have you ever used this on any themeforest submission? Thanks again for your kind help. (Y)

Comment: Yes, I'm using all kinds of escape functions in my themes, depends on the data. For me the `esc_html` would be the best in this case.

FYI - I've dropped support of Redux Framework in favour of standard WordPress tools. As far as I'm concerned, theme submission requirements on official WordPress.org site already require using nothing but pure WordPress. I suppose that in a year or two ThemeForest will have to do the same.

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, sorry. If you find my answer useful, kindly mark it as correct, I would be very greatful :)

Comment: Oh! Yes, of course. :)  I did decide to mark it as my answer when I found the solution.